# Unit Test Failing - Moq Not Invoking Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Given the following, why does this unit test fail saying:

> Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny())

Configured setups:

```
x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny<Step>()), Times.Never
No invocations performed.
```

**Code**:

```
public static SubmissionVersion DeleteStep(IRepository repository, SubmissionVersion version, Guid stepId)
    {
        Step step = repository.GetById<Step>(stepId);
        Level level = step.Level;

        /// Delete child objects
        Step.DeleteNotifications(repository, step);

        /// Delete Step
        version.Steps.Remove(step);
        repository.Save(version);
        repository.Delete(step);

        /// Reorder Levels
        IList<Level> levels = new List<Level>();
        version.Steps.Where(s => s != step).OrderBy(s => s.Level.SortOrder).ForEach(s =>
        {
            if (!levels.Contains(s.Level))
                levels.Add(s.Level);
        });

        Level prevLevel = null;
        levels.ForEach(lvl =>
        {
            if (prevLevel != null)
            {
                lvl.DependsOnLevel = prevLevel;
                repository.Save(lvl);
            }
            prevLevel = lvl;
        });

        /// Delete Level
        if (!levels.Contains(level))
            repository.Delete(level);


        int order = 0;
        List<Step> sorted = version.Steps.OrderBy(c => c.SortOrder).ToList();
        sorted.ForEach(c =>
        {   /// Update SortOrder for list items
            c.SortOrder = order++;
            repository.Save(c);
        });
        return repository.GetById<SubmissionVersion>(version.Id);
    }
```

**Test**

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Call_SubmissionVersionRemoveStepsOnce()
{
    // Arrange
    var ctx = new TestContext();
    ctx
        .SubmissionVersion
        .SetupGet(x => x.Steps)
        .Returns(new List<Step> { ctx.Step });

    // Act
    SubmissionVersion.DeleteStep(
        ctx.Repository.Object,
        ctx.SubmissionVersion.Object,
        ctx.Step.Id.Value);

    // Assert
    ctx
        .SubmissionVersion
        .Verify(x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny<Step>()), Times.Once());
}
```

**TestContext**:

```
internal class TestContext
{
    // Objects
    public Note Note { get; private set; }
    public Section Section { get; private set; }
    public Step Step { get; private set; }
    public SubmissionVersionProjectType SubmissionVersionProjectType
        { get; private set; }
    public SubmissionVersionStatusHistory SubmissionVersionStatusHistory
        { get; private set; }

    // Mocks
    public Mock<SubmissionVersion> SubmissionVersion { get; private set; }
    public Mock<IRepository> Repository { get; private set; }

    public TestContext()
    {
        Note = new Note { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        Section = new Section { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), SortOrder = 0 };
        Step = new Step() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        SubmissionVersionProjectType
            = new SubmissionVersionProjectType { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        SubmissionVersionStatusHistory
            = new SubmissionVersionStatusHistory { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

        SubmissionVersion = new Mock<SubmissionVersion>();
        SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
        SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.Notes.Remove(Note));
        SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.Sections.Remove(Section));
        SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny<Step>()));
        SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.SubmissionVersionProjectTypes.Remove(SubmissionVersionProjectType));
        SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.SubmissionVersionStatusHistory.Remove(SubmissionVersionStatusHistory));

        Repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
        Repository.Setup(x => x.GetById<Note>(Note.Id)).Returns(Note);
        Repository.Setup(x => x.GetById<Section>(Section.Id)).Returns(Section);
        Repository.Setup(x => x.GetById<Step>(Step.Id)).Returns(Step);
        Repository.Setup(x => x.GetById<SubmissionVersionProjectType>(SubmissionVersionProjectType.Id)).Returns(SubmissionVersionProjectType);
        Repository.Setup(x => x.GetById<SubmissionVersionStatusHistory>(SubmissionVersionStatusHistory.Id)).Returns(SubmissionVersionStatusHistory);
        Repository.Setup(x => x.GetById<SubmissionVersion>(SubmissionVersion.Object.Id)).Returns(SubmissionVersion.Object);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the actual test, you setup the Steps getter on the mock to return concrete implementation of Steps {new List<Step> { ctx.Step}}. So instead of calling Remove on the mock, real implementation on the List is called.

Comment: So when the actual code calls remove, that does not remove the item from the mock.object that is passed in?

Comment: It removes the item from the list that is returned through the Steps property. The mock does not track that. In fact I have never seen the setup the way you have it and I don't think it's correct to setup the mock for a "child" method or property. You are mocking SubmissionVersion type sou you should set up only properties and methods of this type. You could verify that an item was removed from the list by checking the Count property directly. If item was removed it will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missing a Setup. Moq would know the .Steps (you already have setup on this), but it would not know the .Remove.

```
   ctx.SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny<Step>()));
```

So your test would be..

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Call_SubmissionVersionRemoveStepsOnce()
    {
        // Arrange
        var ctx = new TestContext();
        ctx
            .SubmissionVersion
            .SetupGet(x => x.Steps)
            .Returns(new List<Step> { ctx.Step });
        var submissionVersion = ctx.SubmissionVersion.Object;

        ctx.SubmissionVersion.Setup(x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny<Step>()));

        // Act
        submissionVersion.DeleteStep(
            ctx.Repository.Object,
            ctx.SubmissionVersion.Object,
            ctx.Step.Id.Value);

        // Assert
        ctx
            .SubmissionVersion
            .Verify(x => x.Steps.Remove(It.IsAny<Step>()), Times.Once());
    }
```

Now you remove the Steps.Remove or call more than once from your SUT (submissionVersion), the test would  fail. Calling only once the  test would pass.

Comment: So when you use MOQ to "Mock" an object, the `Setup` is defining the behavior you are expecting? Is that a fair statement? So even though `Steps` is a collection, and `Remove` is a method on collection, I still have to "Mock" the `Remove` method?

Comment: Correct, normally you would not setup on a method and then verify against it. For instance think of an virtual type which you mock and inject to you SUT and then you can verify a method being called. But in your case you don't have the control over the 'Remove' as it is new List<T> you provided, not a mocked type. So I think the solution is that setup, which means you are going to call the method, but after you calling the SUT, you can verify the method is called or not. There might be a better way but I think the code I provided is sufficient.